# requesting XML through api returns string instead of xml object php

Tags: php, xml, api, magento

I am stuck with this for couple of hours and is not able to figure it out.

The case is I am requesting to an API for the XML data.The API returns the xml data but when i dump that response it displays in the form of string.Whereas when i view the response using postman tool it displays in xml.

My code is :

```
    $response = file_get_contents('http://ws.nielsenbookdataonline.com/BDOLRest/RESTwebServices/BDOLrequest?clientId=XXXX&password=YYYY&from=0&to=20&indexType=0&format=7&resultView=2&field0=1&value0=9781784080808');
var_dump($response);die();
$xmlObj = new Varien_Simplexml_Config($response);
$xmlData = $xmlObj->getNode();
$data = xml2array($xmlData);

function xml2array ( $xmlObject, $out = array () )
{

        foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
            $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ||  is_array ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

        return $out;
}
```

This the the response that i dumped

> string(4977) "BFAU353700101 9781784080808 978-1-78408-080-8 Gentlemen
>   and Sledgers: A History of the Ashes in 100 Quotations Gentlemen and
>   Sledgers A History of the Ashes in 100 Quotations A01 By (author) N
>   Smyth, Rob A01 By (author) N Rob Smyth A01 By (author) N Smyth, Rob
>   A01 By (author) N Rob Smyth 234 153 33 476 BB Hardback 288 8pp col
>   illus Head of Zeus Head of Zeus United Kingdom 267874 267874 G General
>   (US: Trade) WSJC Cricket DC23 796.35865 T15.1 Ball Games: Field &
>   Outdoor The story of cricket's greatest rivalry, told through the
>   tales behind 100 eclectic and entertaining quotations - from the birth
>   of the Ashes in 1882 to the dramatic 2013-14 series. From the
>   celebrated mock obituary following England's first-ever defeat by
>   Australia on home soil in 1882, to the on-pitch insults (or 'sledges')
>   of today, Ashes cricket has spawned nearly as many memorable quotes as
>   it has balls bowled and runs scored. GENTLEMEN AND SLEDGERScharts the
>   ebb and flow of Anglo-Australian cricketing fortunes across 131 years
>   and 314 matches by telling the stories behind 100 memorable Ashes
>   quotations. From fast bowler Jeff Thomson's classic 'I enjoy hitting a
>   batsman more than getting him out. I like to see blood on the pitch'
>   in 1975, to Michael Clark's notorious advice to Jimmy Anderson to 'get
>   ready for a f****** broken arm' in 2013, the quotations embrace quips,
>   insults, examples of the dark art of sledging - and even the
>   occasional considered cricketing judgement. Evoking memorable moments
>   and matches as well as highs and lows in the careers of Australia and
>   England's greatest players, GENTLEMEN AND SLEDGERS is an informal,
>   freewheeling, discursive and entertainingly opinionated history of the
>   Ashes. Rob Smyth is a Guardian and Telegraph sports journalist and the
>   author of The Spirit of Cricket: What Makes Cricket the Greatest Game
>   on Earth, and the co-author of Danish Dynamite: The Story of
>   Football's Greatest Cult Team. 'A wonderful book that is an excellent
>   reminder of cricket's past, some great slices of history backed up
>   with some fantastic pictures ... a must have for all cricket fans and
>   a book that you are able to dip in and out of not just during the
>   summer of cricket' Goodreads. 'The 5-day 5-test Ashes series remained
>   throughout one of the most epic contests in the world of sport and
>   Rob's book helps us to appreciate the reasons why' Counterfire. GB AU
>   IE NZ ZA ROW CA US 20150521 04 Active Harper Collins 20150501 16.99
>   16.99 20150223 02 RRP including tax 26.95 26.95 Local taxes may apply 01 RRP excluding tax 19.99 18.17 20150227 02 RRP including tax 22.99
>   19.99 20150227 02 RRP including tax 20 Available 20150514 21 In stock 21 In stock 20150513 21 In stock 20150513 Macmillan Distribution (MDL)
>   41449 Independent Publishers Group Jonathan Ball Publishers SA 74524
>   HarperCollins Publishers Pty Ltd 115750 Harper Entertainment
>   Distribution Services 262704 HarperCollins New Zealand 115751 BERT
>   GARD ING Y "

This is the XML returned from the API using Postman tool:

```
<Result>
    <clientId>XXXXX</clientId>
    <format>7</format>
    <resultCode>00</resultCode>
    <hits>1</hits>
    <from>0</from>
    <to>1</to>
    <data>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <data>
            <record>
                <ISBN13>9781784080808</ISBN13>
                <ISBN13H>978-1-78408-080-8</ISBN13H>
                <FTS>Gentlemen and Sledgers: A History of the Ashes in 100 Quotations</FTS>
                <TL>Gentlemen and Sledgers</TL>
                <ST>A History of the Ashes in 100 Quotations</ST>
                <CR1>A01</CR1>
                <CRT1>By (author)</CRT1>
                <CCI1>N</CCI1>
                <CNSI1>Smyth, Rob</CNSI1>
                <CR1>A01</CR1>
                <CRT1>By (author)</CRT1>
                <CCI1>N</CCI1>
                <CNS1>Rob Smyth</CNS1>
                <CR1>A01</CR1>
                <CRT1>By (author)</CRT1>
                <CCI1>N</CCI1>
                <CNI1>Smyth, Rob</CNI1>
                <CR1>A01</CR1>
                <CRT1>By (author)</CRT1>
                <CCI1>N</CCI1>
                <CNF1>Rob Smyth</CNF1>
                <HMM>234</HMM>
                <WMM>153</WMM>
                <SMM>33</SMM>
                <WG>476</WG>
                <PFC>BB</PFC>
                <PFCT>Hardback</PFCT>
                <PAGNUM>288</PAGNUM>
                <ILL>8pp col illus</ILL>
                <IMPN>Head of Zeus</IMPN>
                <PUBN>Head of Zeus</PUBN>
                <COP>United Kingdom</COP>
                <IMPID>267874</IMPID>
                <PUBID>267874</PUBID>
                <NAC1>G</NAC1>
                <NAT1>General (US: Trade)</NAT1>
                <BIC2SC1>WSJC</BIC2SC1>
                <BIC2ST1>Cricket</BIC2ST1>
                <DEWS1>DC23</DEWS1>
                <DEWEY1>796.35865</DEWEY1>
                <PRODCC>T15.1</PRODCC>
                <PRODCT>Ball Games: Field &amp; Outdoor</PRODCT>
                <AUSSD>The story of cricket's greatest rivalry, told through the tales behind 100 eclectic and entertaining quotations - from the birth of the Ashes in 1882 to the dramatic 2013-14 series.</AUSSD>
                <AUSLD>From the celebrated mock obituary following England's first-ever defeat by Australia on home soil in 1882, to the on-pitch insults (or 'sledges') of today, Ashes cricket has spawned nearly as many memorable quotes as it has balls bowled and runs scored. GENTLEMEN AND SLEDGERScharts the ebb and flow of Anglo-Australian cricketing fortunes across 131 years and 314 matches by telling the stories behind 100 memorable Ashes quotations. From fast bowler Jeff Thomson's classic 'I enjoy hitting a batsman more than getting him out. I like to see blood on the pitch' in 1975, to Michael Clark's notorious advice to Jimmy Anderson to 'get ready for a f****** broken arm' in 2013, the quotations embrace quips, insults, examples of the dark art of sledging - and even the occasional considered cricketing judgement. Evoking memorable moments and matches as well as highs and lows in the careers of Australia and England's greatest players, GENTLEMEN AND SLEDGERS is an informal, freewheeling, discursive and entertainingly opinionated history of the Ashes.</AUSLD>
                <AUSBIOG>Rob Smyth is a Guardian and Telegraph sports journalist and the author of The Spirit of Cricket: What Makes Cricket the Greatest Game on Earth, and the co-author of Danish Dynamite: The Story of Football's Greatest Cult Team.</AUSBIOG>
                <AUSREV>'A wonderful book that is an excellent reminder of cricket's past, some great slices of history backed up with some fantastic pictures ... a must have for all cricket fans and a book that you are able to dip in and out of not just during the summer of cricket' Goodreads. 'The 5-day 5-test Ashes series remained throughout one of the most epic contests in the world of sport and Rob's book helps us to appreciate the reasons why' Counterfire.</AUSREV>
                <ERSL>GB AU IE NZ ZA ROW</ERSL>
                <NFSRSL>CA US</NFSRSL>
                <PUBPD>20150521</PUBPD>
                <PUBSC>04</PUBSC>
                <PUBST>Active</PUBST>
                <AUSLPUBNAME>Harper Collins</AUSLPUBNAME>
                <AUSLPUBD>20150501</AUSLPUBD>
                <GBPCCPRRRP>16.99</GBPCCPRRRP>
                <GBPCCPRRRPLT>16.99</GBPCCPRRRPLT>
                <GBPCCPLCD>20150223</GBPCCPLCD>
                <GBPCCPTC>02</GBPCCPTC>
                <GBPCCPTD>RRP including tax</GBPCCPTD>
                <USDCCPRRRP>26.95</USDCCPRRRP>
                <USDCCPRRRPLT>26.95</USDCCPRRRPLT>
                <USDCCPRPN>Local taxes may apply</USDCCPRPN>
                <USDCCPTC>01</USDCCPTC>
                <USDCCPTD>RRP excluding tax</USDCCPTD>
                <AUDCCPRRRP>19.99</AUDCCPRRRP>
                <AUDCCPRRRPLT>18.17</AUDCCPRRRPLT>
                <AUDCCPLCD>20150227</AUDCCPLCD>
                <AUDCCPTC>02</AUDCCPTC>
                <AUDCCPTD>RRP including tax</AUDCCPTD>
                <NZDCCPRRRP>22.99</NZDCCPRRRP>
                <NZDCCPRRRPLT>19.99</NZDCCPRRRPLT>
                <NZDCCPLCD>20150227</NZDCCPLCD>
                <NZDCCPTC>02</NZDCCPTC>
                <NZDCCPTD>RRP including tax</NZDCCPTD>
                <UKNBDPAC>20</UKNBDPAC>
                <UKNBDPAT>Available</UKNBDPAT>
                <UKNBDPASLCD>20150514</UKNBDPASLCD>
                <USNBDPAC>21</USNBDPAC>
                <USNBDPAT>In stock</USNBDPAT>
                <AUSNBDPAC>21</AUSNBDPAC>
                <AUSNBDPAT>In stock</AUSNBDPAT>
                <AUSNBDPASLCD>20150513</AUSNBDPASLCD>
                <NZNBDPAC>21</NZNBDPAC>
                <NZNBDPAT>In stock</NZNBDPAT>
                <NZNBDPASLCD>20150513</NZNBDPASLCD>
                <UKADN1>Macmillan Distribution (MDL)</UKADN1>
                <UKADI1>41449</UKADI1>
                <USADN1>Independent Publishers Group</USADN1>
                <SAADN1>Jonathan Ball Publishers SA</SAADN1>
                <SAADI1>74524</SAADI1>
                <AUSADN1>HarperCollins Publishers Pty Ltd</AUSADN1>
                <AUSADI1>115750</AUSADI1>
                <NZADN1>Harper Entertainment Distribution Services</NZADN1>
                <NZADI1>262704</NZADI1>
                <NZADN2>HarperCollins New Zealand</NZADN2>
                <NZADI2>115751</NZADI2>
                <WSLRUK>BERT GARD</WSLRUK>
                <WSLREXUK>ING</WSLREXUK>
                <IMAGFLAG>Y</IMAGFLAG>
            </record>
        </data>
    </data>
</Result>
```

When I dumped $data it returns false.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the url to the API call the exact same with the one used in POSTMAN? (e.g. perhaps the requestView parameter is different and you get the response as plain text?)

Comment: No the url is same i only removed the client id and password here but i used the same  url

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the exact same problem, it is badly formed XML coming from the provider.
The cause is the line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Remove this, or move it to the start of the whole string and it will parse ok.

No ideas why it is it in the middle of the XML string when it should be at the start.

I have raised it with Nielsen support but it's interesting to see you have had the same problem 3 years ago!